# Finding a suitable version of Selenium (automated testing tool) 

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

My project is compatible only with Internet Explorer. I want the test scripts to get generated automatically as it is done in Selenium IDE.Can i use selenium RC to test my application?

I could not use selenium IDE as it can be used only with Mozilla Firefox.

Can you suggest any other free tools for my project.

thanks in advance ...

Comment: Please close this question since you asked it twice

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545079/choosing-an-automated-testing-tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing an automated testing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545079/choosing-an-automated-testing-tool)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you dig around for earlier versions of selenium they are compatible with IE. We use it here for front-end automation via IE6 anyway