# Choosing an automated testing tool

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

My project is compatible only with Internet Explorer. I want the test scripts to get generated automatically as it is done in Selenium IDE.

Can i use Selenium RC to test my application? I could not use Selenium IDE as it can be used only with Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

seleniumrc works with IE. You can specify the browser and the path to it within the config file.

It can be easily integrated into night builds via ant.

stick to writing the testcase in java.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium RC and Selenium Grid are both really good at running tests against IE. You can see all the browsers that are supported by Selenium [here](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#browsers) and Selenium is Designed to write for one browser and work in the rest. THere are a few little quirks that wont work in every browser but 99% of the time it will.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium RC works with IE, but is very buggy with IE 6 (to the point of being unusable). Generating the scripts is not trivial and there are many methods of doing it. We have created a Firefox extension that examines objects via introspection to make click recording easy. There are many options out there but your best bet is to write your tests with Firefox/Firebug (or Chrome). They will make object location much simpler and if you are careful the locator strings should still work in IE.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two answer to you question:

- Besides Selenium, though it has ample of advantages, I am reading about another tool which uses same API which Selenium use. The only changes in API I have seen so far is it reduces the complexity of functions thus making it more easier and simpler for user who is learning. 
  The tool is called 'Helium' and it has 50% (and more) less complex functions and code as Selenium has.
  The only problem with this tool is it is paid tool for learning purpose and for implementing not-so-big scale project you can use it. But yeah after some time its gonna cost you.

I have implemented some code on Helium. Please let me know , if you face any issue initially or you are thinking to implement it.

- Other being, you can use Selenium Builder(http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/selenium-builder-exporting-and-execution/) which is an advanced form of Selenium IDE. It imports your command in different languages and does work more effectively and efficiently as Selenium IDE does(http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/selenium-builder/)

Please let me know , if you have any doubt in any of the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I know [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) is compatible with IE and Firefox. If you want to generate the test code you can use the [Watin Test Recorder](http://watintestrecord.sourceforge.net/)

This of course is implying that you are using .Net

Answer (score 0):

... Or you could just use the .net bindings that comes along with the latest couple of versions, then you can just run 'em through nUnit.

Answer (score 0):

For ex. Selenium IDE users Katalon Recorder might be a good match. Supports different browsers.